# Can i use natralite butter in making puff pastry

Tags: puff-pastry, margarine

I want to make puff pastry, can i use natralite butter for making the same?

Comment: Welcome! This is an international site and I am sure not all readers are familiar with the product you mention. Could you please [edit] your post with a bit more information? Then, while you wait for the community to chime in, I suggest you take the [tour] and browse through our [help] to learn more about how the site works z

Comment: Plus, are you sure you mean “natralite”? My google returns plastic sheeting if I search for the term. Did you mean “nutralite”?

Answer (score 2):

Puff pastry can be made with any fat which won't melt while working the dough (or, at least, in the early stages of working the dough). The higher the softening temperature, the easier it will be to get good results.

I assume that "natralite butter" refers to a type of margarine. Margarine which comes in a tub is intended to be spreadable at refrigerator temperature and has a low melting point, and should not be used for puff pastry or for baking in general. Margarine which comes in sticks will have a higher melting point and is better. The best thing to use (assuming you can't use butter) is shortening, such as Crisco. Shortening has a reasonably high melting point, and a lower moisture content than margarine. Its main problem is that it tastes even less like butter than margarine does, so you may want to mix if the buttery taste is important.